how to configure firewall to do a NAT
i have a k8s cluseter deployed inside a proxmox host.
enter image description here
everytime i deploy an app inside the cluster , i make a NodePoer service for it, ex :30001, and in order to access the app outside the cluster using the public IP, i create a NAT rule for that reason like :
Code:
post-up iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING  -i  vmbr0 -p tcp --dport 30001 -j DNAT --to 172.16.104.107:30001
post-down iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -i  vmbr0 -p tcp --dport 30001 -j DNAT --to 172.16.104.107:30001

now, i have installed an ingress controller inside my cluster and i have deployed an nginx app for test pupose, and i can access from proxmox host :
Code:
curl --header "HOST: nginx.example.com" http://172.16.104.107:30747
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
html { color-scheme: light dark; }
body { width: 35em; margin: 0 auto;
font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>

where 30747 is number of the nodeport for http ans 30755 for https.
but my problem is asking the user to type the port number each time they want to access our HTTP/(S) is not the best way to go. So, we will configure our firewall to do a NAT that look like this:
enter image description here
could you help please to how i can Adjust firewall access-list accordingly. in the NAT ?
thanks
